# What if the FindByIdAsync, Id is null

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

My code looks like:

```
IEnumerable<Booking> Bookings = _repoBooking.GetAll.OrderBy(d => d.BookingDateTime).ToList();

return Json(listErrorMsg(Bookings.Select(a => new
{
    bookingId = a.BookingId,
    bookingDateTime = a.BookingDateTime,
    jobType = a.JobType,
    bookingStatus = a.BookingStatus,
    projectId = a.ProjectId,
    clientId = a.ClientId,
    clientEmail = _userManagerService.FindByIdAsync(a.ClientId).Result.Email
})));
```

The correct JSON object looks like:

```
 {
   "bookingId": 7016,
   "bookingDateTime": "2017-06-13T17:00:00",
   "jobType": "Quote",
   "bookingStatus": "Pending",
   "projectId": 343,
   "clientId": "01d85u46-b753-8635-ba3b-a6458cbv2425",
   "clientEmail": "fake@fakemail.com"
 }
```

However, the problem I have is that if the ClientId is null, it returns an error as the FindByIdAsync is using a null object for it's search.

How would I go about filtering it to only use the FindByIdAsync method if clientId != null or just return " ", if it is.

Should I create 2 separate select statements and join them?

I've put Where clauses nearly everywhere and an if statement won't work for obvious reasons. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating a new anonymous object to serialize?  Why aren't you awaiting the result of `_userManagerService.FindByIdAsync(a.ClientId)`

Comment: Why don't you create a user table in your custom context and store the email there? Then you can use a normal Id (int) and relate your tables to that table. That will make things a lot easier. There are two seperate contexts: the Identity context to identify the user and your custom context for your business information. Keep both contexts seperated. If done well you won't need the Identity context other than when you login. Because the information you need should be in your custom context (so you'll need only one query) and for the current user you can use claims with addidtional information.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there will hit the database once for every unique `clientId` value that is contained in the `Bookings` collection. If it is a small collection this will not be a problem but as soon as it grows it will become very inefficient. A better solution is to get all the user's email addresses based on the client ids found in the collection.

```
var Bookings = _repoBooking.GetAll.OrderBy(d => d.BookingDateTime).ToList();
var clientIds = Bookings.Where(x => x.ClientId != null).Select(x => x.ClientId).ToList();
var emailLookup = _userManagerService.Users.Where(user => clientIds.Contains(user.Id)).ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Email);
```

Replace the line `clientEmail =...` with

```
clientEmail = a.ClientId != null ? emailLookup[a.ClientId] : ""
```

Now you have only 2 database calls, one to get the Bookings and one to get the list of email addresses. You could go even further and reduce it down to one call if you modify the `Booking` relationship to include a reference to `User`.

Answer (score -1):

Try:
clientEmail = a.ClientId == null ? "" : _userManagerService.FindByIdAsync(a.ClientId).Result.Email